# Is there an easy way to release non minified version of react-native to app store using Xcode?

Tags: xcode, react-native

Nevermind the reason why I need to do this, its not important.

Is there a quick way to release non minified version of my react-native app?

Comment: What does "non minified" mean?

Comment: This might help you: https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/first-time-deploying-with-react-native-f524eb3e705d#.4mc4ibcds

By passing `--dev true` to the `bundle` command, you get a bundled version that is not minified, although all performance optimizations will also be disabled, warnings enabled, and other development settings will be activated.

Then you would just need to place the resulting file inside your project, as indicated in the article.

It might not suit your needs, as it is basically a development version of your code, but it might be a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell it's not possible. I'm trying to do the same thing - I've built an MVVM framework that dynamically loads the views from the view models. Works fine in debug mode but the instant it's minified the names all get blown to hell.

Looks like you have to manually duplicate the names as strings in the class if you want to make it work, bit of a nightmare.

Hopefully someone knows a secret that I don't and feels like enlightening us...